# Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `a'

Tags: haskell

```
import Data.List

data Tree a = Leaf a | Node (Tree a) a (Tree a) deriving Show

toTree :: Ord a => [a] -> Tree a
toTree xs = Node (balancedTree (take n xs')) (xs'!!n) (balancedTree (drop n xs'))
    where 
        xs' = sort xs
        n = middle xs

middle :: Num a => [a] -> a
middle xs = fromIntegral ((length xs `div` 2) + 1)

balancedTree :: Ord a => [a] -> Tree a
balancedTree (x:[]) = Leaf x
balancedTree xs = Node (balancedTree (take n xs')) (xs'!!n) (balancedTree (drop n xs'))
    where 
        xs' = sort xs
        n = middle xs
```

This is my code for converting from a list to a binary tree. I know there are many mistakes but I just want to get the types errors sorted before I start debugging. I get the following errors in both the "toTree" method and the "balancedTree" method as they are both really the same and will be condensed into one when the errors are sorted out.

```
ex7.hs:6:38: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `a'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          toTree :: forall a. Ord a => [a] -> Tree a
        at ex7.hs:5:1-32
    * In the first argument of `take', namely `n'
      In the first argument of `balancedTree', namely `(take n xs')'
      In the first argument of `Node', namely
        `(balancedTree (take n xs'))'
    * Relevant bindings include
        xs' :: [a] (bound at ex7.hs:8:9)
        n :: a (bound at ex7.hs:9:9)
        xs :: [a] (bound at ex7.hs:6:8)
        toTree :: [a] -> Tree a (bound at ex7.hs:6:1)
  |
6 | toTree xs = Node (balancedTree (take n xs')) (xs'!!n) (balancedTree (drop n xs'))
  |                                      ^
```

I have tried for hours to fix it by searching stackOverflow but I can't figure it out. The type declaration of "toTree" must stay the same. Also the definition of Tree should stay the same.

My understanding is that "take" required an "Int" and I am giving it an "a". I do not know how I can fix this.

Comment: Did you try to read and understand the error message? What is not clear about the error?

Comment: Sorry, I am a noob which I why I came here. I think it means that take requires an "Int" but I am giving it an "a"

Comment: Your tree structure is wrong. It cannot represent a tree with two data items for example.

Comment: What do you mean sorry?

Comment: I recommend starting with a function `insert :: Ord a => a -> Tree a -> Tree a`. Gets a tree with N items, returns one with N+1 items. Don't muck with sorting and indices.

Comment: I would do it another way, but I have to do it this way as it's an exercise for school.

Comment: If you are talking to someone specific, use the @username convention, then they will get a notification. If you were asking me, I mean exactly what I say. Your tree data structure cannot represent a tree with two data items. You want to try and draw such a tree on a piece of paper, and see why it is impossible.

Comment: You probably need to fire your teacher.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. yeah my teacher is pretty bad. I have to go now but I will be back later to try and fix this. I thought this would work if I have some termination conditions. You're right btw. It prints infinitely.

Comment: change it to `middle :: [a] -> Int`, and it'll fix the type errors. `(drop n xs')` is wrong, should be `drop (n+1)`. `n` is just an index, should be independent of the list's values' type. why shouldn't you also be able to have lists of `Char`s etc.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. maybe the teacher wanted the students to discover for themselves what it means to have a fully balanced tree, what size is it, etc, etc. there is much value in finding problems in a design of a solution, and coming up with fixes yourself while learning, instead of being told the right answer upfront. :) maybe the teacher wanted the students to see for themselves there *is* a problem, in the first place.

Comment: I think drop needs to stay the same @WillNess

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `middle` returns an `a`, not an `Int`. Indeed:

```
middle :: Num a => [a] -> a
middle xs = fromIntegral ((length xs `div` 2) + 1)
```

But in your `balancedTree`, you use it as if it is an index, and `take n`, `drop n`, and `!! n` require `n` to be an `Int`, indeed:

```
balancedTree :: Ord a => [a] -> Tree a
balancedTree (x:[]) = Leaf x
balancedTree xs = Node (balancedTree (take n xs')) (xs'!!n) (balancedTree (drop n xs'))
    where 
        xs' = sort xs
        n = middle xs
```

The type signature does not make much sense either. You can calculate the length over any list, not only from lists that consist out of numbers. You thus should construct a function that returns the *index* in the middle of the list and use that. For example:

```
middle :: [a] -> Int
middle = (length xs `div` 2) + 1
```

That being said, using `length`, etc. is usually *not* a good idea in Haskell. `length` requires *O(n)* time, and furthermore for infinite lists, it will get stuck in an infinite loop. Often if you use functions like `length`, there is a more elegant solution.

Instead of using a "top-down" approach, it might be better to look at a "bottom-up" approach, where you iterate over the items, and on the fly construct `Leaf`s, and group these together in `Node`s until you reach the top.

Comment: You probably want `drop (n + 1) xs'` to avoid storing the middle element at the root *and* in the right subtree. (Or `take (n-1) xs'`).